# Newbie to Python: Imported Lib

Tags: python

I have this structure

```
02.SensorTag/
    sensortag_example.py
    bluepy/bluepy/sensortag.py
    bluepy/bluepy/btle.py
```

So the sensortag_example.py is importing the sensortag.py

```
import bluepy
from bluepy.bluepy import sensortag
```

When I ran the code it complains about the import from the sensortag.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensortag_example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bluepy.bluepy import sensortag 
  File "/home/pi/Development/02.SensorTag/bluepy/bluepy/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import sensortag
  File "/home/pi/Development/02.SensorTag/bluepy/bluepy/sensortag.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bluepy.btle import UUID, Peripheral, DefaultDelegate, AssignedNumbers
ImportError: No module named 'bluepy.btle'
```

I've tried to add a new path but it didin't work.  If I move the program to the first folder bluepy and change the import to "from bluepy import sensortag" it works, but I'll need to import other libs so I don't want to let it in bluepy folder.

I am trying to run this code:
https://gist.github.com/atotto/ae603b962115eef703c0011d8e652ea3

Thanks and best regards,
Edu

Comment: How do you run the code ? Could you provide the exact command and working directory please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sensortag.py` is in the same directory as `btle.py`, add a `.` in front of the import

```
from .btle import UUID, Peripheral, DefaultDelegate, AssignedNumbers
```

This is known as a relative import: https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Answer (score 1):

As both btle.py and sensortag.py are in the same directory so by looking at your error I am assuming that you tried to import it from previous directory. So place from .btle import UUID in sensortag.py should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should create two **init**.py file.

```
02.SensorTag/
    sensortag_example.py
    bluepy/__init__.py
    bluepy/bluepy/__init__.py
    bluepy/bluepy/sensortag.py
    bluepy/bluepy/btle.py
```

Comment: Both folder already have the __init__.py
The first one is empty and the second one has this content:
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import btle
from . import sensortag
__all__ = ["btle", "sensortag"]

Comment: So you shoul use import in sensortag_example.py like
from bluepy.bluepy.btle import UUID, Peripheral, DefaultDelegate, AssignedNumbers